# How do i Make a Bossbar that will Decrease when i Die?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I recently found out about the new Minecraft snapshot that adds new uses to boss health bars. I was wondering if there was a way to make a bossbar that will decrease by 1 every time i die, and when i die 9 times (when the bar depletes all the way) it will set my gamemode to hardcore, therefore causing me to only be able to die 10 times before my game gets deleted. If so, can someone tell me how to create this command?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Well i looked at many tutorials and all i can figure out is that you have to use tellraw commands, but i dont know what actual command i have to put in the tellraw command itself. I watched about 6 Bossbar command tutorials to be exact

Comment: I also figured out that you need to use the totalKillCount command, but i am unaware of how to set up the command Ex: /bossbar set minecraft:{bossbar id} {tellraw command}

Comment: And since this is a fairly new concept, there arent many tutorials on how to make stuff like death counters

Comment: Okay, so you've looked, but what have you *tried*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [wiki on Hardcore mode](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hardcore):

> It is normally impossible to toggle Hardcore mode once the world has been created, though it is possible to use external programs such as NBTExplorer to change it by setting the hardcore tag to either 1 (hardcore) or 0 (normal).

There is no command to change the world to hardcore mode so what you are asking for is not currently possible.

---

Just for fun and since I have never played with 1.13 before today, I built a system which will do what you want except it changes the difficulty to hard when you die the 9th time instead of hardcore mode.  Anyone who sees anything that could be done better, feel free to educate me.

First, a handful of manual commands to enter into chat.

Create an objective to track the number of deaths:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Deaths deathCount
```

Create the bossbar:

```
/bossbar create minecraft:deaths "Deaths"
```

Set the maximum value of the bar to 10:

```
/bossbar set minecraft:deaths max 10
```

Set bossbar to a notched style for easy counting:

```
/bossbar set minecraft:deaths style notched_10
```

Apply bossbar to yourself:

```
/bossbar set minecraft:deaths players @a
```

---

**Now for the command blocks**

*First command block* is a <kbd>Repeat</kbd> <kbd>Unconditional</kbd> <kbd>Always active</kbd> block with the command:

```
execute store result bossbar minecraft:deaths value run scoreboard players get @p Deaths
```

*Second command block* is a <kbd>Chain</kbd> <kbd>Unconditional</kbd> <kbd>Always active</kbd> block with the command:

```
execute if score @p Deaths matches 9 run difficulty hard
```

Comment: Thanks, I have been searching for how to do this for ages!